# Origins of the alphabets for Arabic, Hebrew and Aramaic languages

Tags: writing-systems

I am working on a program to learn some of the most popular non-Western languages: first, Arabic and Hebrew, second, Bengali and Hindu whose scripts are based on Sanskrit, and third, Chinese, Japanese, Korean and Vietnamese. Each one of these language groups has scripts that share common features. What are the origins of these scripts? How can I understand them and use them efficiently to facilitate and improve my learning methodology?

Comment: The Hebrew alphabet currently in use was directly borrowed from Aramaic, replacing [paleo-hebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleo-Hebrew_alphabet)

Answer (score 2):

These scripts can be divided broadly into two historical groups, the Egypto-Semitic group and Chinese, where Chinese and Japanese fall into the latter group, and Korean is sort of outside that dichotomy (it doesn't "derive" from another system, it was created by King Sejong, but it was inspired by Chinese and Indic traditions). Vietnamese is written in a modified version of Latin script. Arabic, Hebrew, Bengali, Hindi also Tamil etc not to mention Greek and Latin have a common origin, namely [Phoenician script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenician_alphabet) via [Aramaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aramaic_alphabet).

Each system has myriad quirks that have developed over the millenia. People have spend many years trying to understand the writing of Biblical Hebrew, so a program to "understand" that script is not likely to come forth any time soon. I suppose what you mean is, a program to help people understand how to write in a given script, presupposing that the student knows the actual language form and just doesn't know how to write it (example: Classical Arabic rama: "he threw" spelled رَمَى). There are various rules of spelling beyond a list of letters and their phonetic interpretation, for example why is the last letter "y without dots" (alif maqsura) when often long a: is written with ا and is that the same as ﺎ ?). Apart from knowing the list of symbols in each writing system, you also have to know details of the structure of these languages, for example "what is a weak verb in Arabic, and how do you tell which glide is deleted?".